# Mi animacion solo funciona al recargarla pero no al hacer scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

veran tengo los siguientes efectos para mi seccion .

```
/* Agregamos la propiedad "opacity: 0" para que los elementos estén ocultos al principio */

.animado-1,
.animado-2,
.animado-3 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Agregamos las clases ".animado-titulo", ".animado-subtitulo" y ".animado-descripcion" a los elementos que queremos animar */
.animado-1 {
  animation: aparecer 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.animado-2 {
  animation: aparecer 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.animado-3 {
  animation: aparecer 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}


/* Creamos la animación "aparecer" */
@keyframes aparecer {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

tambien les muestro el javascript que deberia aplicar esa animacion no solo al recargar si no tambien cuando haga scroll.

```
const elementosAnimados = document.querySelectorAll('.animado-1, .animado-2, .animado-3');

function animarElementos() {
  elementosAnimados.forEach(elemento => {
    const posicion = elemento.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const pantalla = window.innerHeight;
    
    if (posicion < pantalla * 0.8 && posicion > -pantalla * 0.2) {
      elemento.classList.add('animado');
    } else {
      elemento.classList.remove('animado');
    }
  });
}
// Ejecutamos la función al cargar la página
animarElementos();
window.addEventListener('scroll', animarElementos); // Ejecutamos la función cada vez que se hace scroll
```

el punto es que al desplazarme hacia arriba o abajo no veo cambios, solo al recargar y como soy nuevo en esto se me dificulta encontrarel error. aqui les dejo el html por si sirve de algo

```
 <main>
        <section class="services-contenedor" id="servicio">
            <h2 class="subtitulo animado-1">Nuestro servicio</h2>
            <div class="contenedor-servicio">
        
                <div class="checklist-servicio">
                    <div class="service animado-2">
                        <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                        <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>
                        
                        <div class="contenedor-galeria">
                        <img class="tamano-velacion img-galeria" src="img/saladevelacion.JPEG" alt="">
                        <img class="tamano-velacion img-galeria" src="img/saladevelacion2.JPEG" alt="">
                        <img class="tamano-velacion img-galeria" src="img/saladevelacionnew.JPEG" alt="">

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

y una imagen porque no.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es: generar una animación cuando el elemento es visible en pantalla, donde:

- Se debe animar los objetos que se muestran al inicio
- Luego ir animando objetos que van apareciendo a medida que se hace scroll

Javascript tiene una funcionalidad especial para esto que se llama [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), con la cual puedes verificar cuando un elemento entra o sale de su contenedor (por default el viewport) e incluso el porcentaje de intersección entre ambos.

```js
const elementosAnimados = document.querySelectorAll('.animado');

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  observados => {
      for (let o of observados) {
          if (o.isIntersecting) {
            o.target.style["animation-play-state"]="running";
          }
      }
  },{ threshold:0.75}
);

elementosAnimados.forEach(elemento =>observer.observe(elemento));
```

```css
.animado {
  animation: aparecer 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}


@keyframes aparecer {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="1" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="2" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="3" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="4" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="5" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="6" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="services-contenedor animado" id="7" >
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Nuestro servicio</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-servicio">

        <div class="checklist-servicio">
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="n-service"><span class="number"></span>Salas De Velacion</h3>

                <p class ="fuente-parrafos animado-3"> Ofrecemos un entorno acogedor para brindar consuelo a nuestros clientes. En funerales ebenezer, nos esforzamos por brindar servicios funerarios excepcionales que satisfagan las necesidades de cada uno de ellos</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```