# Animaciones al scrollear

Tags: css, angular

Tengo animaciones en css son alrededor de 7 pero cuando entro a la vista se me cargan todas de golpe y quisiera que fuera reconociendo el scroll, he estado buscando pero lo que encuentro es para las animaciones de angular

```
@keyframes f-imagen {
0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-0.75em);
}
20% {
  opacity: 1;
}
80% {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
100% {
  transform: translateZ(-1000em);
}
}

.first-img {
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 8px;
    animation: f-imagen 1s linear;
    @include sm {
        height: 100%;
        animation: f-imagen 2.5s linear;
    }
}
```

js

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-1 order-sm-2">
    <img src="assets/icons/firstland.svg" class="first-img">
  </div>
```

Comment: Mira esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584353/mi-animacion-solo-funciona-al-recargarla-pero-no-al-hacer-scroll/584562#584562

Comment: Gracias es lo que estoy bsucando pero en ese link se encuentra o.target.style y me indica Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
Igualmente me imagino que la ultima linea seria dentro de un metodo que se incie en ngoninit?